# how to fix reset thanks button "current month"

Tags: php

I want to make a plannification and for the moment I have 3 buttons: 
a button to go to the previous month
a button to go to the next month 
and another button that doesn't work but is supposed to go back to the current month

But the problem is with the last button " comeback to current month"
This button did nothing and when i click on it he does nothing and I don't have error message.
Thanks

```
if(isset($_GET['m'], $_GET['y'])) {
    $date_debut = new Datetime((int)$_GET['y'].'-'.(int)$_GET['m'].'-01');
}

if (empty($date_debut)) {
    $date_debut = new Datetime('first day of this month');
}

<a href="?m='.$date_debut->format('n').'&y='.$date_debut->format('Y').'"><input type="button" class="imprimer" value="MOIS EN COURS"></a>
```

Comment: Is a plannification a "calendar"?

Comment: First of all, you can not nest `input` in `a`, that is invalid HTML, they are both “interactive” elements and as such can not be nested. Secondly, what values do you get for the parameters m and y in the actually generated link then?

Comment: ofc I can it works for the 2 others button ...

Comment: @seb Shouldn't you be using `echo` to output the HTML code which you have?

Comment: Yes I used 1 echo for the 3 buttons :/ but the last button didn't work

Comment: @seb 1 echo for 3 buttons?. Do you mind posting more code including how you echo all the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['m'], $_GET['y'])) {
        $date_debut = new Datetime((int)$_GET['y'] . '-' . (int)$_GET['m'] . '-01');
    }

    if (empty($date_debut)) {
        $date_debut = new Datetime('first day of this month');
    }
    echo '<a href="?m=' . $date_debut->format('n') . '&y=' . $date_debut->format('Y') . '"><input type="button" class="imprimer" value="MOIS EN COURS"></a>';
    ?>
```